# How to change element property with JS when it is set by CSS already?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My site's `background-attachment` is set to `scroll` in `CSS`:

```
body {background-attachment: scroll;}
```

I'm looking for a way to change it to `fixed` with `JS` depending on a `condition`. So far I've found two approaches which both do not seem to work:

1.

```
document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
```

2. 

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
```

Approach 2 returns the right property:

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundAttachment);
```

output:

```
scroll
```

but doesn't change it. Is this a cascading problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first setting:

```
document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
```

should work, in the sense that the value of that style should be changed to fixed. However, some browsers, most notably Safari, do not fully support fixed background attachments see `https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment`. I cannot tell from the code given in the question whether that is your problem here or not.

Your second setting:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
```

does not change the setting - as you can see from doing your alert immediately afterwards. Here's info from MDN:

> The object from getComputedStyle is read-only, and should be used to inspect the element's style — including those set by a  element or an external stylesheet.

Without more of your code which will show how you are testing for the condition I can't tell why method 1 won't work but method two certainly can't.

Comment: I am not testing for the condition yet, just trying to find a command that will change the `background-attachment` of my site. I am using chrome. The document is very simple. There is only one declaration of the `background-attachment` in a seperate `CSS` file.

Comment: OK, I seem to have some local issues with my dev-environment. You are right, `document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";` works.